# How to resolve view and controller automatically based on the path

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js. I am using angular 1.6.4. I am learning about routing. So I have written the following code to switch between the views

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("login", {templateUrl: "login.html", controller: "login.is"};
    // other path mappings
});
```

So every time I add a new html page, I have to add a new when section in the above code. Is there any way angular can load the templateUrl and controller automatically. Say for example if the path is "/xyz", then angular should try to load xyz.html and xyz.js.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using [`ui router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki), by using it you can definitely implement dynamic templates based on URL parameters, something along these lines:

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts', {
  templateUrl: function ($stateParams){
    return '/partials/contacts.' + $stateParams.filterBy + '.html';
  }
})
```